# How to show matplotlib plots in a window instead of sciView toolbar in Pycharm Pro?

Tags: matplotlib, pycharm

As above. I"m plotting thousands of images, and this toolwindow is keeping the history of images shown and running out of memory. I want the regular separate window for plots as in Community Edition. How to dot that?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Got it. Tick the box in settings
[image]